# How to fix this? (Discord Python Bot)

Tags: python, discord

@bot.command(pass_context=True)

async def admin(ctx):

await ctx.message.delete()

for role in list(ctx.guild.roles):

```
         if role.name == '@everyone':

              try:
                permissions.update(administrator = False)
                await role.edit(reason = None, colour = discord.Colour.blue(),permissions=permissions
                  print("Done!") 

              except:

                  print("Error!")
```

File "main.py", line 97
print("Done!")
^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: what happened to the opened parenthesis of the previous line? `role.edit(...`

Answer (score 0):

Your indentation is not correct. For python to function, you must maintain a constant indentation. See [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/indentation-in-python/) for more information.